# Migrate tkinter GUIs for remote access?

Tags: python, tkinter, remote-access

I'm no UI or web designer, though I have made a bunch of simple Tkinter-based GUIs that are simple wrappers to test lower-level code and hardware, such as protocol and data acquisition testers for equipment connected over a serial port or network.  Using Python and Tkinter permits my apps to run on every platform supporting Python.

Now I need to migrate my GUIs to support single-user remote access, while still supporting access by local users.  And I'd still like the program to be portable across platforms, and even have it be possible to be made into a binary executable (via py2exe, pyinstaller, py2app, etc.)

Are there any toolkits that support Tkinter-like simplicity?  Ideally, I'd like to do a line-for-line rewrite to swap Tkinter for something else, rather than reimplement or extensively refactor my apps.

I have found [Web2Py](http://www.web2py.com/) and [pyjs/Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/), but they seem to be overkill for my simple needs.  I also searched for a solution based on a single-instance (or single window) VNC or NX or RDP host, but found nothing applicable.

What is the most direct way to "remote-ify" my Tkinter GUIs?

If I do need to completely dump my Tkinter architecture/code and start over from scratch, what approach would best meet my needs?

Comment: Just found [winswitch](http://winswitch.org) and am checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out CherryPy. It's really easy to wrap your head around and get a quick server up and running - it doesn't have the overhead/complexity that a lot of other frameworks impose (Django!!). Unfortunately you will have to rewrite the UI in html, but ultimately it will most likely be worth the effort. Check out Twitter's Bootstrap to get the ball rolling on a quick and attractive UI that just "works".

An example of how concise a CherryPy app can be:

```
import cherrypy

class SessionExample:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index ( self ):
        if cherrypy.session.has_key ( 'color' ):
            out =  "<font color='{0}'>{0}</font>".format(cherrypy.session['color'])
        else:
            out = ""
        return out + ("<form method='POST' action='setColor'>\n"
                      "Please choose a color:<br />\n"
                      "<select name='color'>\n"
                      "<option>Black</option>\n"
                      "<option>Red</option>\n"
                      "<option>Green</option>\n"
                      "<option>Blue</option>\n"
                      "</select><br />\n"
                      "<input type='submit' value='Select' />\n"
                      "</form>"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def setColor (self, color):
        cherrypy.session ['color'] = color
        return "Color set to {}".format(color)

cherrypy.config.update({
    "server.socketPort" = 8080,
    "server.environment" = "development",
    "server.threadPool" = 10,
    "sessionFilter.on" = True
})
cherrypy.root = SessionExample()
cherrypy.server.start()
```

Navigate to localhost:8080 in a web browser and you should see a color picker. Simple!

Comment: Is there a CherryPy example app that uses Tkinter-like widgets (at least buttons and text boxes)?  I'd like to see a working example of the control and data flow so I can get an idea of the work/code required to use it.  And also to use as a template, since I don't know much HTML.

Comment: Once you move to the HTML world control flow works a bit differently. You won't have a "main" or "message handling" loop anymore; instead functions are triggered by loading a URL. That should give you an idea of the control/data flow. Answer updated with a very basic form for selecting a color. I suggest reading more here (teaches you about templates too): http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/GenshiTutorial